# MSIS0038: SAML Message has wrong signature - ADFS error

Tags: windows-server-2012, saml-2.0, adfs, adfs2.1

I was getting this strange error in Windows Server 2012 even after installing the right Signature certificates for SP in ADFS.  The error logs shows something like this :

```
The Federation Service encountered an error while processing the SAML authentication request. 

Additional Data 
Exception details: 
System.IdentityModel.SignatureVerificationFailedException: MSIS0038: SAML Message has wrong signature. Issuer: 'XXX-XXX-XX'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.SamlContractUtility.CreateSamlMessage(MSISSamlBindingMessage message)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolService.Issue(IssueRequest issueRequest)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolService.ProcessRequest(Message requestMessage)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several hours of unproductive debugging I found that this is a known ADFS issue and has nothing to do with validity of certificates, thumbprints, etc..

Microsoft has provided the below update to rectify this issue.

[kb - 2896713](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2896713)

This issue occurs if the system has security update 2843639 installed on Windows 2012 Server.

Comment: Also for Windows 2008 Server