# SAML error for SSO with ADFS - MSIS0038: SAML Message has wrong signature

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs, adfs2.0, passport-saml

Hi I am trying to use SSO to authenticate my client's users directly to my website. My client's IDP is Microsoft ADFS and I am using Passport-SAML (https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml) to configure the SSO process.

After getting to a special URL I give my client (example: www.myClient.myCompany.com ), the user (unauthenticated) is as expected redirected to the client login page.
After he enters his credential, he remains stuck in login page **BUT** the SSO work because the user is authenticated meaning that if he opens a new tab and go to www.myClient.myCompany.com, he will be redirected to my website.

Here the error in ADFS Server Log:

```
The Federation Service encountered an error while processing the SAML authentication request. 

Additional Data 
Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.SignatureVerificationFailedException: MSIS0038: SAML Message has wrong signature. Issuer: 'www.myCompany.co'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.SamlContractUtility.CreateSamlMessage(MSISSamlBindingMessage message)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolService.Issue(IssueRequest issueRequest)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolService.ProcessRequest(Message requestMessage)
```

[image: MSIS0038 Error - Event ID 303]

Thank for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Microsoft ADFS nor Passport-SAML, but I when we had signature errors was because the SHA1 fingerpring of the IDp certificate didn't match the one at our end.

We fixed them by making sure the certificate is correctly formatted and then calculating the fingerpring.

Format:
https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/online-tools/x509-certs/format-x509-certificate
Fingerprint:
https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/online-tools/x509-certs/calculate-fingerprint

Hopefully this is your case

Comment: Hey @s1mpl3, thank you for taking the time to answer. In your case, the SSO wasn't working  at all until you solve your problem? Because in our case the SSO work but we have a problem of redirection for the first login (After the user authenticate with his credential for the 1st time)

Comment: The issue I described was for a single IDp to SP request. Different providers but same error wrong signature.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Passport-SAML guru but the normal causes of this error with ADFS are:

- A signing mismatch - ADFS expects the AuthRequest to be signed and it isn't or vice versa.
- The signing certificate installed in this RP has expired or is the wrong one in the sense that it is not the certificate the client is using.

At the RP level, look at:

Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust

[-SignedSamlRequestsRequired ]
[-SamlResponseSignature ]

or globally:

Get-ADFSProperties

SignedSamlRequestsRequired
SignSamlAuthnRequests

and check:

Get-AdfsCertificate -CertificateType "Token-Signing"

Comment: Hey @nzpcmad, by "this error" you mean the fact that I have a problem of redirection only for the 1st login or you are talking about MSIS0038 in a general manner? 
Do you think my error can happen because cookies saved on the browser? I try to delete all my browser's cookies and it seems to work...

Comment: No - general. In my experience, this problem is not a cookie issue.

Answer (score 0):

(following up from [ADFS and PingFederate SSO : SAML Message has wrong signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019715/adfs-and-pingfederate-sso-saml-message-has-wrong-signature/36032123?noredirect=1#comment86548650_36032123))

We're using a different [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml2-js) and it was a different issue for us (our customer actually had the wrong signature), but during the process of trying to debug, I happened upon [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4acc04b7-aac7-43e9-ba50-9570503045f9/msis0038-saml-message-has-wrong-signature?forum=windowsazureaditpro) that sounds very similar to what you're describing.

The fix is to install [this hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2896713/update-is-available-to-fix-several-issues-after-you-install-security-u). Can you check if your customer is on Windows Server 2008 and 2012, has 2843638 or 2843639 installed, and if so, install the hotfix if they haven't already? Just a shot in the dark...